# How to get HTML select tag elements, option text not value

Tags: jquery

I know how to get the value of a selected option but i am wondering how to get its text.

this is how i access the option using the value ?

```
$('#dropdownId').children('option[value="'+5691+'"]').hide();
```

something like below,

```
$('#dropdownId').children('option[text="'+'some text'+'"]').hide();
```

Comment: Looks like you try to get element by contained text insteed of getting text of element. So you've got a lot of irrelevant answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.children("option:contains('"+text+"')")
```

Comment: how can i lower case the text ? is something like this is possible. lower(text) ?

Comment: yes, native js `.toLowerCase()` method: `.children("option:contains('"+text.toLowerCase()+"')")`

Comment: tnx but i want something like below...... i have this... $('#dd_type_call').children("option:contains('"+'Hello World'+"')").hide();
Instead of this, I want to check like this.
$('#dd_type_call').children("option:lower(contains)('"+'hello world’+"')").hide();

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('#dropdownId').children('option[value="'+5691+'"]').text()
```

Comment: He need to get element not text.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()`.

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/friiks/XXsFy/

Comment: $('#dd_type_call').children("option:contains('"+'Hello World'+"')").hide();
Instead of this, I want to check like this.
$('#dd_type_call').children("option:lower(contains)('"+'hello world’+"')").hide();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="foo">
    <option value="1">foo</option>
    <option value="2">bar</option>
</select>
```

**Java Script:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#foo").change(function(){
        alert($("#foo option:selected").text());
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to achieve some thing like this

```
if($('#dropdownId').children().text()=="some text")
   $('#dropdownId').children().hide();
```

Thanks.